# MYSQL query for every hour

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, aggregate-functions

```
$today = mktime(0,0,0);
$yesterday = $today - 86400;
$this->view->numberyesterday=$db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE `siteid`=".$sid." AND `timestamp` > ".$db->quote($yesterday,'integer')." AND timestamp < ".$db->quote($today,'integer'));
```

I have used the above code to display all the records of yesterday. Now I need to plot the graph for each hour. How can I retrieve the records in every hour from the above query?( like, records within 12-1 AM, 1-2 AM....23-24PM etc)

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I wish I could store the records of each hour in each variable. So that there will be 24 variable for 24 hours. So it is easy to draw the graph.

Answer (score 5):

You did not specify how the output would look like, but it seems like this construct would help you:

```
select Hour(timestamp) transhour, count(*) transcount
from transactions
where yourfilters = yourvalues
Group by Hour(timestamp)
```

The output will look like this:

```
transhour | transcount
======================
0         | 2
1         | 23
2         | 45
3         | 23
...       | ...
22        | 34
23        | 3
```

Warning: if no transactions were performed in a given hour, the output will **omit** this hour (and not bring it back with count zero)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wish I could store the records of each hour in each variable. So that there will be 24 variable for 24 hours. So it is easy to draw the graph. So the query should be something like, $this->view->numberyesterday=$db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE `siteid`=".$sid." AND `timestamp` > ".$db->quote($yesterday,'integer')." AND timestamp < ".$db->quote($today,'integer') AND hour BETWEEN (1,2));

Comment: How can I make the values to be zero when there is no records?